# Combining jsoup results with listView

Tags: android, html, listview, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have got a few parts of my app. One part gets job names parsed from html site using jsoup, the second part shows an ArrayList of results. Now I tried to make my ArrayList show results from jsoup, but on emulator I have got only crashes. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       ......... (Shortened version)
    }

    private ArrayList getListData() {
        ArrayList<JobItem> results = new ArrayList<JobItem>();

        for (int i =0; i<7; i++) {
            JobItem jobData = new JobItem();
            NewThread nT = new NewThread();

            jobData.setHeadline("Job: "+ nT.jobList.get(i)+"\n");
            results.add(jobData);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

}

and

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.infosomething.com")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

                job = doc.select("h2.p-job-title a[href]");
                for (Element jobs : job) {
                    jobList.add(jobs.text()+"\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;



        }
}
```

and

```
public class JobItem {
    private String jobname;
    private String jobcompany;

    public String getHeadline() {

        return jobname;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {

        this.jobname = jobname;
    }
}
```

Separately these two functions work good, but I cannot combine them. I think the problem is with `jobData.setHeadline("Job: "+ nT.jobList.get(i)+"\n");`If I try `jobData.setHeadline("Something something");`, then it works. How to modify it?The main goal is to show a listView of my stored html fragments using an ArrayList. Please help to a newbie.

Comment: Could you post the Stack Trace / LogCat of when it crashes ?

Comment: Looking at your code, I see that your `NewThread` class does not have any `jobList`. Also, you are not actually starting your `NewThread` AsyncTask.